# Unable to find or create a dropdown menu in the navbar for bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

Now before I begin, I can say that I've thoroughly searched every corner of the internet for an answer to this, and I cannot find one.

Going on, I've tried reading any of bootstrap's guides and it's been zero help. I'm using an addon created by someone else that is apparently 'wrapped' in bootstrap, just for the theme/css. All programming and such to the website itself is done by any php scripts that he/I have added to it. Believe me, I've contacted him before and he is zero help.

I have almost zero experience with bootstrap, which would explain my confusion when I'm seeing all these html files being thrown around, whereas I only have .js and .css bootstrap files needed in there.

I have no idea where to begin when attempting to setup a bootstrap dropdown menu, or anything like it. Nothing has been of any help since it just jumps right into saying 'use this html and it works', I don't know where to put it, and I don't know what css edits to make. I know stackoverflow is used so you can get quick short answers to fix your code and such, and I don't mean to ask a whole question such as 'set this up for me' but there is nothing on the internet that is of help, so I'm asking here if anyone has any knowledge on it. Thank you.

If it matters, here is the pre-made theme I'm using: http://bootswatch.com/cyborg/

Edit:
I've gone through all files and every row of each file for the fifth time and I finally picked up on something. The HTML was in my header.php in a seperate folder apart from bootstrap this whole time. Here is the HTML code.

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">

   <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Server Highscores</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>

   <body>
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
     <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
        Dropdown
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
       <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
       <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
       <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
       <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="container">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       </button>
       <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Scoreboards</a>
      </div>
      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      </ul>
     </div>
     <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
   </nav>
   
   <div class="container" style ="min-height:90%;">
```

Also keep in mind that the default names for the tabs and such for the dropdown are just placeholders for now.
This is the entire html part. The dropdown button now appears and I'm very happy about that, although I have some further questions. The button is terribly positioned in the top right. I'm guessing that's when the CSS comes into play, but I am unsure what to put in ".dropdown-menu"'s section of the css. I tried this http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns under the 'alignment' section. None of those tips seemed to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: When you say nav dropdown, do you mean a submenu within the main navbar? Or do you mean a responsive menu that turns into a dropdown at a certain max-width? Also... posting relevant code which you're having trouble with would help you get more answers.

Comment: I mean a submenu within the actual navbar, and I have no relevant code to post unfortunately because there is no code that I can find for it

Comment: Not really giving us much to go on here but I threw an answer up. Should give you somewhere to start, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You're not giving much to go on, but here's how I solved the same problem (using AngularJS but you could translate to vanilla JS pretty easily).

You click your button to expand the dropdown, setting showSubMenu to true as you click it. Then show that div, et voila.

```
<li data-ng-init="showSubMenu = false" ng-click="showSubMenu = !showSubMenu">
   <a>Click Me For Dropdown</a>
</li>

<div data-ng-show="showSubMenu">
   <ul>
      <li><a>Submenu Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a>Submenu Item 2</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm... not sure what you mean here. I'm sorry everyone to be vague in my questions/replies but I'm just a coding noob that only really knows lua/php well. My question up above is really where to put this code, and how - since I know nothing about bootstrap's base/layout

Comment: You're really going to need to learn HTML if you want to be able to do this then. It shouldn't be all that difficult to figure out but if you're asking where and how to put this code, you've got a bit of learning before you'll be able to do it. Best of luck

Comment: Alright, found the issue. It wasn't exactly me knowing html. For some reason in most places this question got really misinterpreted. I was just asking where that chunk of code would go in bootstrap, as I know nothing about bootstrap. Turns out because it is just a 'wrapped' version of bootstrap, I won't really be putting anything in it other than css. I found where to place my html, and it is in there and functional. At this point it is just css. Refer to my most recent edit. Thanks